# Is there a way to make a scrollview extend/shrink as needed in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uistackview, stackview

I have a stackview (which the user can add/remove elements from) inside of a scrollview and I want the scrollview always adjust to have the same height as the stackview so that I don't have to add a bunch of unnecessary space if there's only a few elements in the stackview. Is there any way to make the scrollview's height change to match the stackview's height whenever an element is added to the stackview?

Answer (score 1):

You can use anchors like so,

```
 ScollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints =     
 false
 ScrollView.heightanchor.constrains(equalTo : 
 stackview.heightconstrains).isActive = true
```

Another way if you don't want using auto layout anchors

```
Let height = stackView.frame.size.height
ScrollView.frame.size.height = height
```

Let me know if it solved your issue

Comment: Neither of those is working for me - the first one doesn't work because once a new constraint is set it conflicts with the original one. For the second one, I don't know why it doesn't work, it just doesn't change the size of the scrollview.

Comment: Post you UI code please

Comment: Regarding the above comment with conflicting constraints, the key is to set the priority on the constraint to a lower value. That allows the other constraints to override once this constraint becomes in conflict.

Answer (score 0):

you need just manage the control inside the stackview scrollview automatically adapt the height accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why but I couldn't get any method of editing the scrollview to work, so what I did was make a function that removes the previous scrollview and adds a new one whenever new content is added to the view.